# Microsoft graph API notification retry time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm working on a sync server that keeps the Office 365 events and my calendering app in sync. I subscribed to a push notification for user's event calendar that has a custom single extended property.

[The documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/webhooks) says if the sync server doesn't respond with a `2xx` message, the notifications will be resent in periodic intervals. I tried by bringing my server down for some time and in this interval I did some changes to the events for which I was expecting notifications. Then I brought the server up again and it took some time(10-15 mins) for Microsoft to send old queued notifications.

Any idea what is the interval that Microsoft sends queued notifications when `2xx` is not received?

Comment: There isn't a fixed interval between attempts. The longer you are down, the longer the interval between attempts (try, wait `x`, try, wait `x+y`, try,  etc.)

Comment: Thanks, @MarcLaFleur. Is there a way the service can request for immediate re-queue of the pending notifications? I can use this mechanism to get the pending notifications at service startup.

Comment: It isn't, no. You could cancel the subscription and recreate it but this would only notify you of changes made since you recreated it. The guidance is to allow the system to self-correct. There are exceptions to the rule but that really depends on your specific scenario.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I didn't find a single documentation which explains how this notification retry policy works. I don't know why this isn't documented clearly. It's really necessary to know how the notification retry queue works.

Comment: It's not necessary. If you need to know how the internals of the MSGraph retry system, then you need to rethink how you're doing it. It IS enough to know that it will retry. If you MUST receive it, build a highly available system that dumps it onto a queue and then handle it from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

The latency is in the table here -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#latency

| Resource | Average latency | Maximum latency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| calendar | Less than 1 minute | 3 minutes |

but the retry times aren't published.

It really comes down to designing your own system to be fault tolerant and highly available rather than relying on an MSFT retry policy to work around your (potential) outages.

The easiest way to handle this is to take the message and immediately place it into your own queue and return 202. Accept the message for further processing and you're in control of how/when to handle it.